# DNS Resolution of CNAME records in Route53 fails in some AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

A hostname that is a CNAME record resolves correctly outside of an AWS environment, but within AWS, it resolves correctly from EC2 instances in some accounts and fails (NXDOMAIN) consistently in other accounts.

A hostname that is an A record resolves correctly everywhere.

I have used nslookup and dig to check name resolution.

To rule out failures due to bad cache entries in some of the resolvers on the resolution path, I ran the dig command 200 times on the machine where resolution fails.

If I use the +trace option of dig, I see the CNAME result in all 200 cases, and different resolvers are used in different cases.

If I remove the +trace option, the resolution fails in all 200 cases.

Does anyone have any clue on what’s wrong?

See outputs below..

```
# dig SUCCEEDS with +trace
$ dig +trace es-stage.guardinex.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5.2 <<>> +trace es-stage.guardinex.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       518400  IN      NS      M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
;; Received 239 bytes from 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2) in 0 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20221125050000 20221112040000 18733 . I5it4epK25laf74ZFhYWR/3wGGjsFroYCirdzIyMrzs4vJMU0XLVs+Ws veV+vnXqmVuN5HkJJwcR5Ff43mCZ+KhypfArYQ/RNtGazBKz0gX5wxZ6 2ub1SVr3318yAMtl3iN2N44RB6ZBiEKlur0heBFoBFqW8LpR7/89PqYV lHOTKZGDKGCNZedLPa+ukQcgp2YRdXOZFV3kNgXeKGlxYfK9Nv8eVqnP Tc5bQY1DlZvU026MB9SJG4lY0v4AXPt0gu0iyenC50RTIdVbiq/R2PHj hn92tvVzOZkmyWvchHTP5uvyRAm/ktkqQL+R6i9B+/fqIdyuEw2YEgZI ktNOhw==
;; Received 1185 bytes from 192.112.36.4#53(G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET) in 45 ms

guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-270.awsdns-33.com.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-986.awsdns-59.net.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1152.awsdns-16.org.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1855.awsdns-39.co.uk.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q2D6NI4I7EQH8NA30NS61O48UL8G5 NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20221119052449 20221112041449 53929 com. hYUTcpX5l7kJAr78hLqD/FuTq2H6w3My4YrnqfpuOkpuv3n4r5aLG63b vo3cRytvqc2usP+YMVpPDRkzPbGbOJZL0M6R2U8w0oQPcSstUL27jjJ7 xgInCLHW1iRj4NlGFay8pE5Fw3Rz9P65s0AXX0QEeQ6VwKZmW9MXDlp/ H14cc7l2zzG6ZXrHUNJwzid1r6kONuadYYxYA58dLPdq5g==
LJ4SG1LGI8CMLK7J08OKU0C0S3K2UNVB.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - LJ4T61EATV8L0OEI963F53KIKOBLB229 NS DS RRSIG
LJ4SG1LGI8CMLK7J08OKU0C0S3K2UNVB.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20221116051525 20221109040525 53929 com. QzChq+rEDnhDgTdLf/qq0Jle7AKE1HPg0dfdx1+mzjxYsUTjIQNj3FQ1 OXE7vffUqLumBHuqtlWLZqYUqosElGv3PVGyhR7u50goIVOcTdZ1hjtd NivYJ81eaZPmvjcLdxmMN4fel7kRoDmS/y81oIbadOpu9ebJsocF5p8h R79mQ6rz8CfNYuGcVmJLgwwDRYQRzX+PLhJ3eJJZ3NyQSg==
;; Received 753 bytes from 192.43.172.30#53(i.gtld-servers.net) in 19 ms

es-stage.guardinex.com. 3600    IN      CNAME   search-guardinex-es-stage-qh6d74ilnpedsg2si4pvd4g2ea.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1152.awsdns-16.org.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1855.awsdns-39.co.uk.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-270.awsdns-33.com.
guardinex.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-986.awsdns-59.net.
;; Received 278 bytes from 205.251.195.218#53(ns-986.awsdns-59.net) in 1 ms


# dig FAILS WITHOUT +trace
$ dig es-stage.guardinex.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5.2 <<>> es-stage.guardinex.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 47207
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;es-stage.guardinex.com.                IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
guardinex.com.          300     IN      SOA     ns-1536.awsdns-00.co.uk. awsdns-                                                                                                                                                             hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 12 12:43:00 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135


# dig SUCCEEDS WITHOUT +trace (on a different AWS account)
$ dig es-stage.guardinex.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5.2 <<>> es-stage.guardinex.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4172
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;es-stage.guardinex.com.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
es-stage.guardinex.com. 300     IN      CNAME   search-guardinex-es-stage-qh6d74                                                                                                                                                             ilnpedsg2si4pvd4g2ea.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com.
search-guardinex-es-stage-qh6d74ilnpedsg2si4pvd4g2ea.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com.                                                                                                                                                              60 IN A 54.177.125.22
search-guardinex-es-stage-qh6d74ilnpedsg2si4pvd4g2ea.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com.                                                                                                                                                              60 IN A 52.53.54.78

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 12 12:49:32 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 173
```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause was that the accounts where resolution fails have their own private DNS zone which contains the guardinex.com entry, and that conflicts with the guardinex.com entry in the public DNS zone....

Removing the private DNS zone and it works now.
Moved the records to the public zone.